# how to call a restful web service , which takes a object as parameter from Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have a restful web service, which takes an object as parameter.

At angular side, I am using the Restangular to invoke the GET Web Api. When i tried to invoke the web api, I am getting 415 error.

Please let me know, how to go ahead :(

Regards,
ng

Comment: can you post your code and what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: Thanks for replying.I figured it out that the problem is Webservice api should not be a GET method as its taking a composite object as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out that the problem is Webservice api should not be a GET method as its taking a composite object as parameter.